# Check App Settings in OneDrive

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

Actually, I may be jumping the gun, so to speak. Given the "default" settings in Windows 8.1 (Pro, if that matters):

[image: PC Settings screenshot]

- Does this mean `%users%\user_name\AppData\*` is being synced?
- So if there is an issue with OneDrive (e.g. network, bug, can't sync, can't start, etc), what does this really mean?

Hence the question - I'd like to see how one would check these settings in OneDrive (I can see files, but not these "other" resources - assuming that they actually are synced).

At the end of the day, I'm trying to figure out why certain applications start "misbehaving" (just out of the blue) and in certain cases, the "solution" is to clear application cache - which is in AppData.

Thanks for any help/info/advice.

---

Update:

For *your* OneDrive data, *other* than files:

1. Go to [One Drive](https://onedrive.live.com) and login with your Windows user/pwd
2. Click the "Gear" (Options) at top right

   - You'll see `Device Backups`(among other settings/options).

I don't see any other data (e.g. `AppData`) so unless otherwise corrected, as @Ramhound commented below, that's probably it.

Comment: Yes;  Its being synced.  But what does it have to do with OneDrive.  Only one setting in that screenshot is for OneDrive specifically.  The App Data is for `Windows Store` applications not your traditional desktop applications.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, that answers it - `Windows Store` only apps, not other apps whose settings/cache could be in `AppData` (e.g. Visual Studio, etc.). Do you have an official link where that is specified? Thanks.

Comment: Besides the Windows 8 features website, not really, also payed attention when Windows 8 was released.

Comment: You can run Process Monitor by SysInternals and monitor what directories that setting scans to confirm what Ramhound says is true or not.